# Selecting selected item in Dropdownlistfor atomatically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have a dropdownlistFor in a partialview liek this

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
     Referre To: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SenderPosition_Id, ViewBag.senderPositionsList as SelectList, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
 </div>
```

this Dropdownlistfor is filled in controller like this:

```
 List<ReferrableUsersViewModel> senderPositionsList = new List<ReferrableUsersViewModel>();       
 using (WebECartableEntities dc = new WebECartableEntities())
 {                          
    senderPositionsList = dc.Positions.Where(m => m.usr_Id == User.Identity.Name).Select(x => new ReferrableUsersViewModel
                {
                    SenderPosition_Id = x.ID,
                    Name_Position = x.Title
                }
                ).Distinct().OrderBy(m => m.Name_Position).ToList();


    ViewBag.senderPositionsList = new SelectList(senderPositionsList, "SenderPosition_Id", "Name_Position");
 }
```

I want if the DropdownlistFor has one Item, it be selected automatically, but if it has more than one items, let the user selects it.
how can I do that in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller action you can check if count of the collection is 1 set the `SenderPosition_Id` of your model object to that one like:

```
if(senderPositionsList.Count == 1)
{
     model.SenderPosition_Id = senderPositionsList.First().ID;
}
......
......
return View(model);
```